# Points calculated using this elliptic curve point multiplication do not lie on the curve and this class brings Arithmetic exception

Tags: java, cryptography, elliptic-curve, arithmeticexception

I get stack on my error of point multiplication using standard projective coordinates.  I don't know  what i missed but the multiplied points do not lie on the curve and some times it outputs something like **Arithmetic Exception: integer is not invertible.**

```
public class ECPointArthimetic {

    EllipticCurve ec;
    private BigInteger x;
    private BigInteger y;
    private BigInteger z;
    private BigInteger zinv;
    private BigInteger one = BigInteger.ONE;
    private BigInteger zero = BigInteger.ZERO;
    private boolean infinity;

    public ECPointArthimetic(EllipticCurve ec, BigInteger x, BigInteger y, BigInteger z) {
        this.ec = ec;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        // Projective coordinates: either zinv == null or z * zinv == 1
        // z and zinv are just BigIntegers, not fieldElements
        if (z == null) {
            this.z = BigInteger.ONE;
        } else {
            this.z = z;
        }
        this.zinv = null;
        infinity = false;
        //TODO: compression flag
    }

    public BigInteger getX() {
        if (this.zinv == null) {
            this.zinv = this.z.modInverse(this.ec.getP());
        }
        return this.x.multiply(this.zinv).mod(this.ec.getP());
    }

    public BigInteger getY() {
        if (this.zinv == null) {
            this.zinv = this.z.modInverse(this.ec.getP());
        }
        return this.y.multiply(this.zinv).mod(this.ec.getP());
    }

    public boolean pointEquals(ECPointArthimetic other) {
        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (this.isInfinity()) {
            return other.isInfinity();
        }
        if (other.isInfinity()) {
            return this.isInfinity();
        }
        BigInteger u, v;
        // u = Y2 * Z1 - Y1 * Z2
        u = other.y.multiply(this.z).subtract(this.y.multiply(other.z)).mod(this.ec.getP());
        if (!u.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            return false;
        }
        // v = X2 * Z1 - X1 * Z2
        v = other.x.multiply(this.z).subtract(this.x.multiply(other.z)).mod(this.ec.getP());
        return v.equals(BigInteger.ZERO);
    }

    public boolean isInfinity() {
        if ((this.x == zero) && (this.y == zero)) {
            return true;
        }
        return this.z.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) && !this.y.equals(BigInteger.ZERO);
    }

    public ECPointArthimetic negate() {
        return new ECPointArthimetic(this.ec, this.x, this.y.negate(), this.z);
    }

    public ECPointArthimetic add(ECPointArthimetic b) {
        if (this.isInfinity()) {
            return b;
        }
        if (b.isInfinity()) {
            return this;
        }
        ECPointArthimetic R = new ECPointArthimetic(this.ec, zero, zero, null);
        // u = Y2 * Z1 - Y1 * Z2
        BigInteger u = b.y.multiply(this.z).
                subtract(this.y.multiply(b.z)).mod(this.ec.getP());
        // v = X2 * Z1 - X1 * Z2
        BigInteger v = b.x.multiply(this.z).
                subtract(this.x.multiply(b.z)).mod(this.ec.getP());

        if (BigInteger.ZERO.equals(v)) {
            if (BigInteger.ZERO.equals(u)) {
                return this.twice(); // this == b, so double
            }

            infinity = true; // this = -b, so infinity
            return R;
        }

        BigInteger THREE = new BigInteger("3");
        BigInteger x1 = this.x;
        BigInteger y1 = this.y;
        BigInteger x2 = b.x;
        BigInteger y2 = b.y;

        BigInteger v2 = v.pow(2);
        BigInteger v3 = v2.multiply(v);
        BigInteger x1v2 = x1.multiply(v2);
        BigInteger zu2 = u.pow(2).multiply(this.z);

        // x3 = v * (z2 * (z1 * u^2 - 2 * x1 * v^2) - v^3)
        BigInteger x3 = zu2.subtract(x1v2.shiftLeft(1)).multiply(b.z).
                subtract(v3).multiply(v).mod(this.ec.getP());
        // y3 = z2 * (3 * x1 * u * v^2 - y1 * v^3 - z1 * u^3) + u * v^3
        BigInteger y3 = x1v2.multiply(THREE).multiply(u).
                subtract(y1.multiply(v3)).subtract(zu2.multiply(u)).
                multiply(b.z).add(u.multiply(v3)).mod(this.ec.getP());
        // z3 = v^3 * z1 * z2
        BigInteger z3 = v3.multiply(this.z).multiply(b.z).mod(this.ec.getP());

        return new ECPointArthimetic(this.ec, x3, y3, z3);
    }

    public ECPointArthimetic twice() {
        if (this.isInfinity()) {
            return this;
        }
        ECPointArthimetic R = new ECPointArthimetic(this.ec, zero, zero, null);
        if (this.y.signum() == 0) {
            infinity = true;
            return R;
        }

        BigInteger THREE = new BigInteger("3");
        BigInteger x1 = this.x;
        BigInteger y1 = this.y;

        BigInteger y1z1 = y1.multiply(this.z);
        BigInteger y1sqz1 = y1z1.multiply(y1).mod(this.ec.getP());
        BigInteger a = this.ec.getA();
        // w = 3 * x1^2 + a * z1^2
        BigInteger w = x1.pow(2).multiply(THREE);
        if (!BigInteger.ZERO.equals(a)) {
            w = w.add(this.z.pow(2).multiply(a));
        }
        w = w.mod(this.ec.getP());
        // x3 = 2 * y1 * z1 * (w^2 - 8 * x1 * y1^2 * z1)
        BigInteger x3 = w.pow(2).subtract(x1.shiftLeft(3).multiply(y1sqz1)).
                shiftLeft(1).multiply(y1z1).mod(this.ec.getP());
        // y3 = 4 * y1^2 * z1 * (3 * w * x1 - 2 * y1^2 * z1) - w^3
        BigInteger y3 = (w.multiply(THREE).multiply(x1).subtract(y1sqz1.shiftLeft(1))).
                shiftLeft(2).multiply(y1sqz1).subtract(w.pow(2).multiply(w)).mod(this.ec.getP());
        // z3 = 8 * (y1 * z1)^3
        BigInteger z3 = y1z1.pow(2).multiply(y1z1).shiftLeft(3).mod(this.ec.getP());

        return new ECPointArthimetic(this.ec, x3, y3, z3);
    }

    public ECPointArthimetic multiply(BigInteger k) {
        if (this.isInfinity()) {
            return this;
        }
        ECPointArthimetic R = new ECPointArthimetic(this.ec, zero, zero, null);
        if (k.signum() == 0) {
            infinity = true;
            return R;
        }

        BigInteger e = k;
        BigInteger h = e.multiply(new BigInteger("3"));

        ECPointArthimetic neg = this.negate();
        R = this;

        int i;
        for (i = h.bitLength() - 2; i > 0; --i) {
            R = R.twice();
            boolean hBit = h.testBit(i);
            boolean eBit = e.testBit(i);

            if (hBit != eBit) {
                R = R.add(hBit ? this : neg);
            }
        }

        return R;
    }

    public ECPointArthimetic implShamirsTrick( BigInteger k,
    ECPointArthimetic Q, BigInteger l){
        int m = Math.max(k.bitLength(), l.bitLength());
        ECPointArthimetic Z = this.add(Q);
        ECPointArthimetic R  = new ECPointArthimetic(ec,zero,zero,null);

        for (int i = m - 1; i >= 0; --i){
            R = R.twice();

            if (k.testBit(i)){
                if (l.testBit(i)){
                    R = R.add(Z);
                }else{
                    R = R.add(this);
                }
            }else{
                if (l.testBit(i)){
                    R = R.add(Q);
                }
            }
        }
        return R;
    }
}
```

Here are the curves I used :

```
package NISTCurves;
import ecc.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class P192 implements ECDomainParameters {

    String p192X = "188da80eb03090f67cbf20eb43a18800f4ff0afd82ff1012";
    String p192Y = "07192b95ffc8da78631011ed6b24cdd573f977a11e794811";
    String p192B = "64210519e59c80e70fa7e9ab72243049feb8deecc146b9b1";
    String p192P = "6277101735386680763835789423207666416083908700390324961279";
    String p192Order = "6277101735386680763835789423176059013767194773182842284081";
    String p192A = "-3";
    BigInteger p = new BigInteger(p192P, 16);
    EllipticCurve ec =
        new EllipticCurve(p,
        new BigInteger(p192A).mod(p),
        new BigInteger(p192B, 16));
    ECPointArthimetic G = new ECPointArthimetic(ec, new BigInteger(p192X,16), 
               new BigInteger(p192Y,16),null);
    BigInteger order = new BigInteger(p192Order, 16);

    @Override
    public BigInteger getP() {
        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public EllipticCurve getECCurve() {
        return ec;
    }

    @Override
    public BigInteger getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    @Override
    public ECPointArthimetic getGenerator() {
        return G;
    }
}
```

Specification of Elliptic curve domain parameters

```
package NISTCurves;
import ecc.ECPointArthimetic;
import ecc.EllipticCurve;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public interface ECDomainParameters {
    public BigInteger getP();
    public ECPointArthimetic getGenerator();  
    public EllipticCurve getECCurve();
    public BigInteger getOrder();
}
```

Elliptic curve digital signature Algorithm implementation is here.
In this code there is main function so use this to test Exception.

```
package ecc;
import NISTCurves.ECDomainParameters;
import NISTCurves.P192;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

/**
 *
 * @author Gere
 */
public class ECDSA {

    private BigInteger r, s;
    ECDomainParameters param;
    private PrivateKey prvKey;
    private PublicKey pubKey;
    BigInteger zero = BigInteger.ZERO;
    private BigInteger one = BigInteger.ONE;
    private MessageDigest sha;

    public ECDSA() {
        try {
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void initSign(PrivateKey prvKey) {
        this.prvKey = prvKey;
        param = prvKey.getParam();
    }

    public void initVerify(PublicKey pubKey) {
        this.pubKey = pubKey;
        param = pubKey.getParam();
    }

    public void update(byte[] byteMsg) {
        sha.update(byteMsg);
    }

    public byte[] sign() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        BigInteger c = new BigInteger(
                                   param.getP().bitLength() + 64,  Rand.sr);
        BigInteger k = c.mod(param.getOrder().subtract(one)).add(one);
        while (!(k.gcd(param.getOrder()).compareTo(one) == 0)) {
            c = new BigInteger(param.getP().bitLength() + 64, Rand.sr);
            k = c.mod(param.getOrder().subtract(one)).add(one);
        }
        BigInteger kinv = k.modInverse(param.getOrder());
        ECPointArthimetic p = param.getGenerator().multiply(k);
        if (p.getX().equals(zero)) {
            return sign();
        }
        BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(sha.digest());
        BigInteger r = p.getX().mod(param.getOrder());

        BigInteger s = (kinv.multiply((hash.add((prvKey.getPrivateKey()
                                  .multiply(r)))))).mod(param.getOrder());
        if (s.compareTo(zero) == 0) {
            return sign();
        }

        System.out.println("r at sign: " + r);
        System.out.println("s at sign: " + s);

        byte[] rArr = toUnsignedByteArray(r);
        byte[] sArr = toUnsignedByteArray(s);
        int nLength = (param.getOrder().bitLength() + 7) / 8;
        byte[] res = new byte[2 * nLength];
        System.arraycopy(rArr, 0, res, nLength - rArr.length, rArr.length);

        System.arraycopy(sArr, 0, res, 2 * nLength - sArr.length,
                      sArr.length);
        return res;
    }

    public boolean verify(byte[] res) {

        int nLength = (param.getOrder().bitLength() + 7) / 8;

        byte[] rArr = new byte[nLength];
        System.arraycopy(res, 0, rArr, 0, nLength);
        r = new BigInteger(rArr);

        byte[] sArr = new byte[nLength];
        System.arraycopy(res, nLength, sArr, 0, nLength);
        s = new BigInteger(sArr);
        System.out.println("r at verify: " + r);
        System.out.println("s at verify: " + s);
        BigInteger w, u1, u2, v;
        // r in the range [1,n-1]
        if (r.compareTo(one) < 0 || r.compareTo(param.getOrder()) >= 0) {
            return false;
        }

        // s in the range [1,n-1]
        if (s.compareTo(one) < 0 || s.compareTo(param.getOrder()) >= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        w = s.modInverse(param.getOrder());

        BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(sha.digest());
        u1 = hash.multiply(w);
        u2 = r.multiply(w);

        ECPointArthimetic G = param.getGenerator();
        ECPointArthimetic Q = pubKey.getPublicKey();

        // u1G + u2Q

        ECPointArthimetic temp = G.implShamirsTrick(u1, Q, u2);
        v = temp.getX();
        v = v.mod(param.getOrder());

        return v.equals(r);
    }

    byte[] toUnsignedByteArray(BigInteger bi) {
        byte[] ba = bi.toByteArray();
        if (ba[0] != 0) {
            return ba;
        } else {
            byte[] ba2 = new byte[ba.length - 1];
            System.arraycopy(ba, 1, ba2, 0, ba.length - 1);
            return ba2;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] msg = "Hello".getBytes();
        byte[] sig = null;
        ECDomainParameters param = new P192();        
        PrivateKey prvObj = new PrivateKey(param);
        PublicKey pubObj = new PublicKey(prvObj);
        ECDSA ecdsa = new ECDSA();
        ecdsa.initSign(prvObj);
        ecdsa.update(msg);
        try {
            sig = ecdsa.sign();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        ecdsa.initVerify(pubObj);
        ecdsa.update(msg);
        if (ecdsa.verify(sig)) {
            System.out.println("valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

Here PrivateKey class

```
package ecc;
import NISTCurves.ECDomainParameters;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

/**
 *
 * @author Gere
 */
public class PrivateKey {

    private BigInteger d;
    private ECDomainParameters param;
    private BigInteger one = BigInteger.ONE;
    private BigInteger zero;
    private PublicKey pubKey;

    public PrivateKey(ECDomainParameters param) {
        this.param = param;
        BigInteger c = new BigInteger(param.getOrder().bitLength() + 64,
                new SecureRandom());
        BigInteger n1 = param.getOrder().subtract(one);
        d = c.mod(n1).add(one);
        pubKey = new PublicKey(this);
    }

    public BigInteger getPrivateKey() {
        return d;
    }

    public ECDomainParameters getParam() {
        return param;
    }
}
```

PublicKey class

```
package ecc;
import NISTCurves.ECDomainParameters;

/**
 *
 * @author Gere
 */
public class PublicKey {
    private ECDomainParameters param;
    private ECPointArthimetic Q;

    public PublicKey(PrivateKey privObj) {
        param = privObj.getParam();
        Q  = param.getGenerator().multiply(privObj.getPrivateKey());
    }

    public ECDomainParameters getParam() {
        return param;
    }

    public ECPointArthimetic getPublicKey() {
        return Q;
    }
}
```

Elliptic curve

```
package ecc;
import java.math.BigInteger;

/**
 *
 * @author Gere
 */
public class EllipticCurve {

    private BigInteger a;
    private BigInteger b;
    private BigInteger p;

    public EllipticCurve(BigInteger a, BigInteger b, BigInteger p) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.p = p;
    }

    public BigInteger getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public BigInteger getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public BigInteger getP() {
        return p;
    }       
}
```

Rand class

```
package ecc;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

/**
 *
 * @author Gere
 */
public class Rand {
    public static final SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();     
}
```

Elliptic Curves interface

```
package ecc;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public interface ECConstants{
    public static final BigInteger zero = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    public static final BigInteger one = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    public static final BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
    public static final BigInteger three = BigInteger.valueOf(3);
    public static final BigInteger four= BigInteger.valueOf(4);
}
```

Comment: You could post the actual stack trace to help us help you.

Comment: That error doesn't seem to involve your `ECPointArthimetic` class in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important errors are in NISTCurves.P192: p and the order are in base-10, not in base-16. Also, when you construct the EllipticCurve-object, you provide the parameters in the wrong order. Your method requires `(a, b, p)`, but you call it with `(p, a, b)` (so my guess about `p` not being prime was correct).

Another problem is in your verify-method, when you unwrap `r` and `s`. Since they are in unsigned format, you should use `new BigInteger(1, rArr)` instead of the normal constructor.

With those changes your code works for me (I can validate the signatures - I have not verified the correctness of the implementation).

---

(Old answer below:)

Since you have not given us the code that matches the stacktrace, this will merely be a guess:

During elliptic curve addition (with a curve over a prime field), you should only be calling `BigInteger.modInverse()` with the prime `p` (the order of the prime field) as the modulus.

The most probable way for this to fail sporadically with "BigInteger not invertible" is if `p` is not actually a prime.

Where are you getting `p` from? Try inserting

```
if(!ec.getP().isProbablePrime(100)) throw new RuntimeException("P is not a prime");
```

somewhere.

Comment: I used NTST curves i.e P192. do u need my code to send u to see the details of errors and help me to fix it?

Comment: @ClickmitWg: We need to see the code in order to help you find the problem. Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: I just included the all the code  you can test it using java netbeans ide 7. u will get an ArithmeticException.

Comment: thank you man i really appreciate your help. after correcting my errors the code works!

Answer (score 0):

From the JDK java code for `BigInteger`:

```
 // Base and modulus are even, throw exception
 if (isEven())
     throw new ArithmeticException("BigInteger not invertible.");
```

It seems that for the `modInverse()` method, the `BigInteger` may not be an even number.

Comment: The ArithmeticException is in the ECDSA which contains the main fuction